# BSPWM blank screen

Tags: arch-linux, bspwm

I was determined to battle this through without having to ask for help ... yet here I am.

I'm fairly new to this but I just can't get bspwm loading up with anything.  Entering startx just gives me a blank screen. No error messages / cursor / responsiveness when attempting a superkey + Return for a urxvt console or any other keybinding.  Just nothing.

Setup:

Arch Linux

Xorg 
bspwm 0.9.7-10-g2ffd9c1

urxvt (9.22)

Ryzen 3 2200g CPU with Radeon Vega graphics,

I first installed the xf86-video-ati driver and when that did not work, used mesa. The issue persists.

Here are my configs:

~/.xinitrc :
ix.io/2dPX

~/.config/bspwm/bspwmrc :
ix.io/2dQ4

~/.config/sxhkd/sxhkdrc :
ix.io/2dQ5

Xorg log (I notice no errors):
ix.io/2dQb

Both bspwmrc & sxhkdrc  have file permissions as rwxr-xr-x

I simply can't see where I'm going wrong.  Can anyone see the mistake? Or anything I can provide to put some more light on this?

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Did you install `sxhkd`?

Comment: I didn't even see there was an sxhkd to install! Makes perfect sense.. just saw no reference to it from arch entry. It solved the issue - thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of reasons why the (example) configuration of [bspwm](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Bspwm) might not work, but in your case it's either because the configuration directories are not accessible (which is unlikely) or you simply don't have [`sxhkd`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Sxhkd) installed. Either way the output of `startx` should tell you the problem, e.g.

```
/home/user/.config/bspwm/bspwmrc: line 3: sxhkd: command not found
```

`sxhkd` is only an optional dependency to `bspwm` so you have to install it explicitly if you want to use it.

```
# pacman -S sxhkd
```